# How to create a route to a controller method which is called by a POST AJAX request

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax

I am trying to figure out how to create a route to a controller method which is called by a POST ajax request in jQuery. I have a function that uses AJAX to update the setup time, which receives data from a select_tag. Here is the following code for that method:

```
    ,update_setup_time: function(e) {
    var d = $('#setup_form_popup').val();
    $.ajax({
        url: '/events/update_setup_time_p',
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: d,
        success: function() {
            alert(d + "how are you doing?");
        }
    });
}
```

I want the URL to call the method update_setup_time_p, which is a method in the controller. However, how do I route to this within the route.rb file? Any and all help is appreciated.

Comment: Didn't fix the problem ... not sure why but there is still a routing error. I understand that resources :events creates a POST path to the create action of the controller. Just not sure why there is still that error

Comment: alright, I changed the http request to PATCH, and that seems to work. But the id is identifying with

Comment: update_setup_time_p, here is the error:

Comment: ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound - Couldn't find Event with 'id'=update_setup_time_p

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this.

```
post '/events/update_setup_time_p', to: 'your_controller#update_setup_time_p'
```

Comment: still getting a routing error, says there is no path

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
$.ajax({
  beforeSend: function(xhr) { xhr.setRequestHeader('X-CSRF-Token', $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content'))},
  type: 'POST',
  url: '/events/update_setup_time_p',
  data: d,
  success: function() {
      alert(d + "how are you doing?");
  }
});
```

Comment: Alright, I changed the http request to PATCH, and that seems to work. But the id is identifying with update_setup_time, here is the error: ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound - Couldn't find Event with 'id'=update_setup_time_p

Comment: please paste the console log of AJAX call

Comment: ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound - Couldn't find Event with 'id'=update_setup_time_p [WHERE `events`.`location_id` IN (4470, 9, 4469, 45, 32, 5, 120, 50, 49, 33, 71, 256, 61, 47)]:
  activerecord (4.2.5.1) lib/active_record/relation/finder_methods.rb:324:in `raise_record_not_found_exception!'
  activerecord (4.2.5.1) lib/active_record/relation/finder_methods.rb:444:in `find_one'
  activerecord (4.2.5.1) lib/active_record/relation/finder_methods.rb:423:in `find_with_ids'
  activerecord (4.2.5.1) lib/active_record/relation/finder_methods.rb:71:in `find'

Comment: Started PATCH "/events/update_setup_time_p" for 127.0.0.1 at 2016-06-14 10:26:40 -0400
Processing by EventsController#update as JS
  Parameters: {"45"=>nil, "id"=>"update_setup_time_p"}

Comment: what action do you want to perform? please share your controller code and routes.

Comment: ended up getting it, looked at the ruby documentation online and wasn't passing an id to the url method